# How do I fix a broken git merge from the wrong origin branch?

Tags: git, merge

A central git repository we use has two branches that diverged a long time ago. Someone accidentally merged the old branch into the newer one, causing some conflicts.

Now I have a merge commit sitting at the top of the newer branch, that looks like this:

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Merge: xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx
Author: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Date:   Fri Sep 12 16:04:23 2014 -0400

    Merge branch 'master' of xxxxxx:xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx into working-branch

    Conflicts:
        Gemfile.lock
        config/xxxx.rb
        config/xxxx.yml
        public/.xxx/xxxxxxx.xml
```

What actually happened here? Is this a failed merge? If so, why did it show up on the remote? How can I tell if any other files got changed? Do I need to try to revert this change or simply roll back these four files?

I've been advised to do a hard reset to the commit before the merge and then force push it back to the repository. What possible strange effects should I be on the lookout for if I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a failed merge, that's a *successful* merge ... or at least, "success" from git's point of view. Someone—let's call him Moe, for the guy who Merged—did a "git merge" that stopped with conflicts on four files.  Then Moe told git that he, Moe, had resolved the conflicts that git found, creating the successful merge commit.  (Maybe Moe *did* resolve them correctly, or maybe not: git does not know, and neither do we.)

Having created the merge commit, Moe went on to make it available to you (it's now "published"; assuming you use a push model with a central server, this means Moe pushed the merge).  That is how you got it and the answer to "why did it show up on the remote?".  (All this assumes you got the merge from the server; if you did it yourself, you're "Moe" and it's available to you because this is your repository in the first place.)

Let's take the rest one part at a time...

#### "What actually happened here?"

Almost certainly, Moe did a `git pull remote-name master` while on branch `working-branch`.  The `pull` command is, in essence, just `git fetch` followed by `git merge`: fetch from the named remote, and then merge (into the current branch, which was `working-branch`) from the named branch(es) as they were seen on the remote at the time of the fetch.<sup>1</sup>  Then he fixed conflicts, or at least told git he did, and committed.

#### "How can I tell if any other files got changed?"

A merge commit is simply a commit with two or more parent commits.  The "first" parent is the branch on which the merge was made (`working-branch` above) and the remaining parent(s) is/are the branches that were merged-in (the `master of xxx...`, above).

As with any commit, to see what changed between "some previous commit"—usually "the immediate parent"—and that commit, you use `git diff` and tell it to compare the previous commit to that commit.  For an ordinary (single-parent, non-merge) commit `1234567`, for instance, you could do this with:

```
git diff 1234567^ 1234567
```

(add `--name-only`, `--name-status`, `--stat`, or whatever `git diff` options you like to select how the diff is presented).  If the ordinary commit is the tip of branch `b`, you can spell this with `git diff b^ b` instead, for instance: the point is to name the parent (`b^`, `1234567^`, or its actual raw commit-ID) and then name the commit itself.

(Side note: this hat `^` suffix is special syntax for "parent", which is part of the general [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) syntax.  Plain hat means `^1`, the first parent; `^2` means the second parent; `^3` means the third parent, if there is a third parent; and so on.  We'll make use of this below.)

There's a short-hand way to show this exact diff (and the log message as well) with one command: `git show`.  Give `git show` a name or ID for an ordinary commit, and it will show you the log message and the diff against that commit's first and only parent.  If you ask `git show` to do this for a *merge* commit, however, it does something a bit different: it shows you a "combined diff".

Remember, a merge commit is a commit with *at least two parents*.  This means that there are at *least two diffs* to generate: first-parent vs the merge, and second-parent vs the merge.  (In fact, there's one for each parent, but more-than-two-parent merges are relatively rare, so we can simply concentrate on the "two" case.)

If you want to see which files changed, without any status or actual diff, you want `git diff --name-only`.  Pick one or the other parent, name it, and name the merge.  Let's say the merge commit is name-able as `HEAD`.  Then:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD
```

will compare the first parent of `HEAD` to `HEAD`, and show you which files changed in terms of that comparison.

To see which files changed from the *second* parent, name the second parent:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD^2 HEAD
```

and so on.

There is, naturally enough, a short-hand way to do this series of `git diff`s as well, using `git show`: add the `-m` flag, and it will do a comparison with each parent.  (Note that if you *leave out* the `-m` flag, `git show` will show you a "combined diff", which only shows—quoting the manual—"files which were modified from all parents."  This is not what you want: if file `foo.txt` was modified in one `-m` diff but not in the other `-m` diff, it's not "modified from all parents" and `git show` won't show it.)  So:

```
git show --name-only -m HEAD
```

will do the trick (and includes the log message and parent for each diff, so you can tell which one is from which parent).

#### "Do I need to try to revert this change or simply roll back these four files?"

Andrew C [has already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25874249/1256452) that reverting the merge leaves you with a different problem to solve later.  It does, however, avoid the problems caused by doing a "history rewrite".  These problems occur (and *can* occur) *only* for those who have the "pre-rewrite" history; and you say in a comment:

#### "I don't want to do the merge at all - it was entirely a mistake."

This suggests that, above, where I'm talking about Moe, the guy who Merged, I'm actually talking about *you*.  You didn't get this merge from someone else, you did it yourself.

If that's the case, that's actually a *good* thing, because maybe only *you* have this history, with this merge that you would like to remove.  That would mean that no one else can see problems caused by you removing the merge from history.

Doing a `git reset --hard` will alter the tip-of-the-branch as stored in the branch name, in your local repository.  This can, in effect, "remove the merge" ... in your local repository (only).  That is, if the history currently looks like this:

```
...- o - o - * - M   <-- HEAD=working-branch
               /
...- o - o - o       <-- (other ID, probably stored in FETCH_HEAD)
```

and you `git reset --hard HEAD^`, this tells git to re-point `working-branch` from commit `M` (the merge) to the commit marked `*`.  This is because `git reset` adjusts whatever branch `HEAD` names, to make it point to the commit given as the argument.  Since `HEAD^` names commit `*`, and `HEAD` names `working-branch`, the `reset` command makes `working-branch` point to commit `*`.

(The `--hard` simply takes the work directory along for the ride, along with the index/staging-area.  Resetting the index is the default, and `--hard` adds the work-dir.)

Commit `M` remains in your repository, but has nothing pointing to it.<sup>2</sup>  Therefore it *seems* to be removed from history, and eventually, it really will be.

#### "Do a hard reset to the commit before the merge and then force push it..."

You only need the force-push step if you already pushed the merge (or got it because someone else pushed it: you really did get it from "Moe").  However, if it *was* pushed, someone else may have it (like Moe himself).  If you force-push, those folks must account for your change.

Let's say, for description sake, that Larry and Curly also have Moe's merge: they have their own copies of the repository, and they have `git fetch`-ed the merge from the remote.  Furthermore, let's say their version of the remote is named `origin`.

If Larry has a local branch `working-branch` that is tracking `origin/working-branch`, then:

- He's "behind" `origin/working-branch` and thus doesn't have the commit yet on his local branch: all he has to do is `git fetch`.  This will update his `origin/working-branch` and he will be "less behind" now, because `origin/working-branch` actually went backwards one.
- He's "even with" `origin/working-branch`: he must still `git fetch`, but once it's done, he must also re-point his own `working-branch`, to discard the merge commit.  The easiest way is to `git checkout working-branch` followed by `git reset --hard origin/working-branch`.
- He's "ahead of" `origin/working-branch`: now he has to do the most work of all.  He still must `git fetch` as always, but afterward, he must rebase his new, post-merge commits onto the now-pre-merge `origin/working-branch` and drop the merge commit.  When his `git fetch` finishes he'll be *more* head than before, for the same reason that the first case became "less behind", but the first one of those "ahead" commits is that unwanted merge, and he must discard it from *his* `working-branch`.

  There are several ways to do this; git 2.0 makes it easier; see other stackoverflow questions and answers for more details.

Curly must do the same things Larry must do, but if Larry is "behind" so Larry has it easy, Curly might still be "ahead" and have to work relatively hard.

---

<sup>1</sup>More specifically, the way `git fetch` works, anthropomorphized,<sup>3</sup> is this:

1. Call up the remote.  Ask him: "Hey, whaddaya got?  What branches and tags do you have, and what commit IDs do they map to?"
2. Take that list of names (branches and tags, or more generally, "references") and figure out what to bring over and what to ignore.
3. Converse some more to find out what additional objects, if any, are needed to get all necessary commits, trees, blobs, etc.  Bring all those over.
4. Last, store the resulting commit IDs and references names somehow.

Step 4 has some special magic: when `git fetch` is run the way it is by `git merge`, the IDs are stored in `FETCH_HEAD`.  When run in other ways, or with a new enough version of git, they're stored as "remote tracking branches" (through the `fetch =` lines associated with the remote).  (New versions of git always update the remote tracking branches, even when using `FETCH_HEAD`, so for this particular case you may get both actions.)

The system is easiest to think about in terms of updated remote-tracking branches: your git calls up their git, finds out what they have, and updates your remote-tracking branches.  Your git also updates these when you "git push", which is the other time your git calls up their git on the Internet-phone.  Thus, your remote-tracking branches are simply "what they had, last time git checked".

The `pull` script predates some of this, so it uses `FETCH_HEAD` in slightly complicated ways, but it ends up working the same as with a very modern git and a separate `git fetch` step: your get gets their git's branch or branches, stashes them away in `FETCH_HEAD`, and then merges using the `FETCH_HEAD` stuff.

<sup>2</sup>Actually, there's a reflog entry that points to it.  You can find these with `git reflog` or using the `name@{history-specifier}` syntax.  However, reflogs eventually expire: they're meant for, among other things, fixing various "oops" type errors, not for permanent storage.

<sup>3</sup>"Don't anthropomorphize computers, they hate that." —source unknown

Comment: This is by far the best explanation of this I've seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Undo the merge with git reset and then redo the merge again

**Step 1) Undo the merge:**

```
git reset --hard xxxxxxx~ # xxxxxxx is the name of working branch
```

**Step 2) Do the merge again**

```
git merge xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx # e.g.: origin/master
```

From this point , is **NOT** recommended to do a force push, the best thing you can do is solve the conflicts and then commit. If you found any problem again, go back to step 1

**Step 2b) (alternative to Step 2) Do rebase**

```
git rebase xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx  e.g.: origin/master
```

If you do rebase you will be able to merge commit by commit or your work over xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx (rebase is the same as cherry-pick all your local non-pushed commits on top of remote branch), it sounds tedious at first but it will allow you to have more control on how to merge each atomic change

**Step 3) Make new changes**

Even if you need to discard changes from remote branch (personally, I would coordinate with my coworkers before doing this), avoid using force pushes, instead you can use checkout with path to bring old content to current version and commit it again on tip of branch (this also will allow you and your teammates to clearly see what are you doing via diffs). Examples

```
git checkout xxxxxx~ . # e.g. xxxxxx could be master
git checkout xxxxxx@{2} .
git checkout XXXX4f42134 .
etc...
```

NOTE: use **git log** and **git reflog** to locate the commits with the contents you need on your local history

**Step 4) Push your changes (without force push)**

```
git push
```

If your push is rejected again (due to new changes on repository), do a **git fetch** a go back to step 2

Comment: I don't want to do the merge at all - it was entirely a mistake. The two remote branches are supposed to stay separate at this point.

Comment: Also, this is on working-branch, not master, so that first step should be:

     git reset --hard working-branch~

no?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the bad merge is still at the branch tip lock down your repo so it doesn't accept any changes.

You have two options.
1) Destroy the history that this ever happened.
2) Revert the merge.

The first results in cleaner history, but can cause problems for other downstream developers (they need to "recover from an upstream rebase" as described in the `git rebase` help pages).  Also, the first trick only works if the merge commit is the branch tip.

The second is generally safer, but causes issues if you ever need to actually re-merge the branch.

Option 1

```
git checkout working-branch
git reset --hard HEAD^1
git push -f
```

And now help all your colleagues recover from an upstream rebase

Option 2

```
git checkout working-branch
git revert -m 1
git push
```

In terms of your questions

We can't tell if the merge is bad or not without looking at the changes.  Somebody performed a merge and pushed it, that's all we know.  You can see what files where changed with `git diff BAD_MERGE_SHA^1..BAD_MERGE_SHA`

Comment: I did a diff on the merge commit and the one before it, and there were no changes. Only the conflicts were listed in the log.

Comment: What are the issues caused "if you ever need to actually re-merge the branch"?

Comment: When you do a merge two things happen - 1) You merge the changes over 2) You create merge history.  When you revert, you are only undoing the changes, not the history.  So `git merge` would say "already merged".  This goes into more detail https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't pushed the merge, you can just delete your repo and re-clone it. Nothing will be changed on the server. If you already pushed the merge, then you can REVERT the change and push the change to undo the merge.